# myanim2 css property is not getting applied in ie9

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Im using the css property  myanim2, and it is working fine in browsers like chrome and firefox.But it is not working in ie.
It is working in chrome and firefox with the below css hack.

```
    -moz-animation: myanim2 2s infinite; -webkit-animation: myanim2 2s infinite
```

May I know how we can make this work in ie also.

Thanks,
Balaji.

Comment: ie9 doesn't support css3 entirely you would have to use javascript to make up the animations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how exactly we can use the javascript to get that myanim2 effect

Comment: ok may be in the ready function , I need to append all the styles that I need, will try that, thanks for your help Marcio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for IE9 you would use the -ms-filter prefix for any CSS3 property. However, Ie9 does not support the CSS3 animation property.

So this animation(myanim2) will not show up in Ie9

Comment: Thanks Maria,is there any alternative then

Comment: I cannot say anything without looking at what that animation does. Its not a default animation. Its a custom animation which must be written in the CSS. Can you paste that animation?

Comment: {position: absolute; width: 40px; height: 40px; cursor: pointer; -moz-animation: myanim2 2s infinite; -webkit-animation: myanim2 2s infinite; z-index: 1000;
animation-name: crecer_img2;
   animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-direction: alternate;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-timing-function:linear;
   animation-fill-mode:both;}

Comment: You will have to use Jquery plugins for this.. Check out this link. it will help you.. http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-animation-tutorials/